# ods parser in node.js not working

Tags: node.js, excel, parsing, ods

I am looking for ODS parser in node.js. Currently I am using [excel-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-parser)
 for parsing xls and xlsx but it cant parse ODS files.

I looked for other npm modules but no one is supporting ODS files.

I tried [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) but its giving me error "unsupported file type".

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

```
  if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
  var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.ods');
```